# php mail function problem

Tags: php, email, function

this is my code so far

```
function send_email() {

$email = $_POST['signup-email'];
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];

$to = "the1nz4ne@hotmail.com";
$subject = "Email from
RateMyLife.com"; $body = "Hi ,$firstname $lastname, this is an email from RateMyLife.com"; $headers = "From:info@iphoneappgmz.com";

mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

exit();

}

$existingSignup = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM signups WHERE signup_email_address='$email'");   
if(mysql_num_rows($existingSignup) < 1){
    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $time = date('H:i:s');
    $password = md5($passwd);
    $insertSignup = mysql_query("INSERT INTO signups (signup_email_address, signup_date, signup_time, firstname, lastname, password, year, day, month, gender) VALUES   ('$email','$date','$time','$firstname', '$lastname', '$password', '$year', '$day', '$month', '$gender')");
    if($insertSignup){ //if insert is successful
       send_email();
    }
```

the email is not send...

thanks i cant figure out what is the problem.

Comment: does this work? in a file with nothing else: mail('your_email_address', 'test', 'test');

Comment: are you getting any error messages?

Comment: I recommend you using the [PHPMailer class](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) or any other option instead of the simple `mail()` function.

Comment: This code is vulnerable to sql injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be a multitude of reasons... Are you on windows or linux server?

Check phpinfo to see if sendmail is correctly configured (sendmail_path).

If it is correctly configured, check why emails is not being sent in your smtp server log messages, check this for more details: http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#101588

If you don't have the sendmail correctly configured, you can still use an account you have in some SMTP server to send your emails. For that you should use a PHP lib to facilitate your work, for example, check this: 
http://swiftmailer.org/

Also, test this php code to send yourself the email and see if it works:

```
mail('YOUREMAIL@EXAMPLE.com', 'My Subject', 'test message');
```

Comment: didn't know about swiftmailer. Being from Fabien Potencier (the guy behind the Symfony framework) must be good. Thanks for the comment @AlfaTeK

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if your two queries succeeded?

```
$existingSignup = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());
$insertSignup = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());
```

if either fails, they return boolean FALSE. If the first fails, then `mysql_num_rows()` will fail as it expects a mysql result handle, not a boolean. And if the second fails, then $insertSignup will be false and your `if()` will never trigger.